# Put key and value to Map<String, ?> ... cannot be converted to CAP#1

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I saw some simillar topics but those didn't answer my question and didn't solve my problem.

I have got method which is part of my authorization process.
I would like to add some `key` and `value` to my `Map`.
I've got  a method which looks like:

```
@Override
    public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        OAuth2Authentication authentication = super.extractAuthentication(map);
        ...
    }
```

If I try to do something like:

```
 map.put("authorities", new ArrayList<>());
```

compiler always complains that

```
incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>
            map.put("authorities", new ArrayList<>());
                                                ^
    reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that ArrayList<E> conforms to CAP#1
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

only variable which pass is `null` but I want to add some `Collection` or another object.

I don't understand `?` while I don't know what is it extending from?

Comment: You are not supposed to put stuff into that map. Are you sure you understand what you are supposed to do in `extractAuthentication`?

Comment: I don't see how `extractAuthentication` works without a cast (and that may not even work in this context)  `Map<String,?> map` could be any type of map with a String key and may not be compatible with `OAuth2Authentication`.  And  `?` in that context means unknown type.  And a map holding different types of values is not very wise as it would require casting upon retrieval.

Comment: @Sweeper I try to do some workaround after migration to new SpringSecurity. I use old OAuth server which gives me token with `scopes` but in new SpringSecurity that information gets lost during authentication process. What I want to achieve is to copy `scopes` into `authorities` with `ROLE_` prefix to keep compability new SpringSecurity with "scoped" access token.
I know that's not correct way, but it's to keep testing until I deeply understand spring security flow and reconfigure it right way.

Comment: So _that's_ your question. Ask _that_ instead (and add more details!), not how to add things to a `Map<String, ?>`.

Comment: @Sweeper Actually putting to map was what I wanted to ask :) Migration to new SpringSecurity is a general topic and (for sure) I will come back in another question.

Comment: I'm suggesting that your question might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @WJS You have deleted your previous comment which actually led me to solution with putting to that map. 
Inside that method I need to try cast that map (in example):
`((Map<String, List<String>>) map).put("authorities", extractScopes(map));`
Thanks

Comment: Casting that map is really *not* a solution to your problem.  You really need to get your types right in the first place.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're right and I need to understand this whole authorisation process more deeper. What is also complicating is fact that a lot of IOS and Android apps uses current `accessToken` structure, and I can't just change it instantly. For now it's test that migration of SpringBoot is possible to keep system working.
@Sweeper I can see your point and you're right, but first I need to understand more whole problem to ask clever question and provide efficient configuration information.